# IntPtr.ToInt32 with Bitwise operator causes OverflowException on 64-bit process

Tags: c#, winforms, bitwise-operators, wndproc, intptr

I want to override some functionality in a control, by disabling zooming when the Ctrl button is clicked and the mousewheel is moved. This works fine on 32-bit processes but on 64-bit processes, I get an overflow by converting the IntPtr to an Int32. How can I rework this so that it works on both 32-bit and 64-bit processes? I can't use bitwise operators with IntPtrs.

Should my constants instead be set to long and then do IntPtr.ToInt64()? Would that work properly on both 32-bit and 64-bit processes? Anything I need to worry about if I make that change?

```
private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
private const int MK_CONTROL = 0x0008;
//Prevent CTRL+Mouse Wheel from Zooming
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
       if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() & MK_CONTROL) != 0)
       {
            // Ignore CTRL+WHEEL
            return;
       }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: If you have a 64 bit pointer (on a 64-bit process) what are you expecting `ToInt32` to do exactly?

Comment: @mjwills: Some message parameters are `IntPtr`, to make them big enough to carry a pointer, but they aren't actually pointers depending on the message ID.  The question seems to be about a small numeric value stored in one of these pointer-sized fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the existing .NET callbacks that already unwrap the parameters correctly.  In WinForms there is the [`Control.OnMouseWheel` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousewheel.aspx).  The modifier keys are available via the [`ModifierKeys` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs m)
{
    if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
    {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)m).Handled = true;
        // Ignore CTRL+WHEEL
        return;
    }

    base.OnMouseWheel(m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not work with the ScintillaNet control (available via Nuget) as the control still zooms. The WndProc method seems to work when I change the constants to long and the convert the IntPtr to Int64

Comment: @jjdem: Ahh, dotPeek revealed that there's this [`HandledMouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) whose express purpose is disabling default behavior of the mouse wheel

Comment: that you very much @BenVoight, it works great with your added change